# Rest api manager encapsulation required or not

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, encapsulation

I am currently designing a software in which I have to use a rest client. I have decided to use a particular library, but am stuck whether I should use it directly or add a custom encapsulation layer. To make myself more clear, suppose i have to make a request from a function named `getAuthInfo`.

> Doing it directly

```
function getAuthInfo() {
    return someLibrary.get(path, headers);
}
```

> Adding Encapsulation layer

```
/* Adding an abstraction layer on top of the library */

import myEncapsulation;

function getAuthInfo() {
    return myEncapsulation.get(path, headers);
}

---------------------------------------------

/* myEncapsulation module */

function get(path, headers) {
    return someLibrary.get(path, headers);
}
```

The reason why I am asking is because the pace at which things change in javascript world, the library i am using today might do a complete rewrite causing breaking changes or a new library might come out which better supports my use case.

In any such case, if I implement using the first method, I will have to make changes all across the app, but in the second case I will have to make changes in a single module.

But the downside I feel to the second method can be that, there is a little overhead to implement the module and that I will have to maintain very cautiously and document properly for the EncapsulationModule.

What do you guys suggest ??

Comment: What I usually do is think about how hard would it be to test my code. In this scenario, are you able to easily mock `someLibrary` library? If not, definitely, write a wrapper that can be easily stubbed. If yes, weight in the other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a judgement call that only you (or your team or your manager) can make.

You must weigh the costs/effort of writing an [anti-corruption layer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used) now versus the additional effort it would take to find all usages of the external library later when you want/need to replace it.

A large part of this will also depend on how likely you think it will be that the library needs to be replaced during the lifetime of your project.